# Need to push Git changes to another branch

Tags: git

I made a mistake pushing 2 sets of changes to the master branch. But I did not Sync yet (I use Visual Studio).

I've now created a branch off master that I want to move these changes to. How can I do that? Either with the git command line or Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you mean by not Sync yet? If you didn't push to the remote yet, you can `reset` without worries. You said you have created a newly branch just for these changes, so, when creating a branch of your master's HEAD, the changes are already in the newly branch, and just do `git checkout master` followed by `git reset HEAD~2` to erase the last 2 commits.

If your branch was already created than move to it and do `git cherry pick <hash>`, you can get a commit of every branch, just put the referenced hash. You can use `git log` to get the hash or `git reflog` if you've for some reason lost some commits.

Comment: Thank you, I was making it too complicated trying to figure it out.

Comment: @DavidThielen It's normal, git takes a time to learn. Try to use command line more often, later use VS.

Answer (score 1):

The safe and easy approach is to cherry-pick the changes onto the new branch, and then use `git revert` to create a commit that undoes the changes on the master. Don't get involved in editing history unless you absolutely need to, even locally.

Comment: I just tried that in Visual Studio and got "an error has occurred, nothing to commit." The changes are only on my system for the master branch - is that the problem?

Comment: @DavidThielen if the changes are only in your machine so is easy, you don't need to "rewrite repository history". just do `git reset`